# Android App Templates?

Tags: android, sdk, templates

Are there Android app templates, similar to the iPhone SDK templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean UI templates, i would say no. there *are* a lot of code examples from google and others demonstrating simple UIs that you can base your work on, but no hard coded "templates" that build your app for you. What android does provide is all the tools you need to effortlessly design simple UIs in a matter of minutes using the SDK. If you are new to android dev, you should check out google's code examples.

If that is not what you meant, i found [this](http://mobilebytes.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/template-engine-for-android-development/) example demonstrating what the author describes as a Template Engine for android

hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Application templates have been added in [ADT 20](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html).

Quoting from [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-sdk-tools-revision-20.html)

> Application templates: Android ADT supports a new application
>   templates for creating new application, blank activity, master-detail
>   flow, and custom view. These templates support the Android style guide
>   thus making it faster and easier to build beautiful apps. More
>   templates will be added over time.